# Error when building React project with Vite: 'default' not exported by 'react/jsx-runtime' in @preact/signals-react v1.3.6

Tags: reactjs, signals, vite, preact

**Description**: I'm encountering an error when building my React project with Vite. The error message mentions an issue related to exporting 'default' from 'react/jsx-runtime' in the package @preact/signals-react v1.3.6.

**Context**: I'm using Vite version 4.2.0 and @preact/signals-react version 1.3.6 in my project. The error appears during the build process but not during development.

**Problem**: The error message is:

> 'default' is not exported by 'react/jsx-runtime', imported by
> 'node_modules/@preact/signals-react/dist/signals.module.js'

### **Attempted Solution:**

I tried downgrading @preact/signals-react to version 1.1.1, and this seems to have resolved the issue during the build.

**Actual Result:** The error mentioned above occurred with @preact/signals-react version 1.3.6, but it was resolved after downgrading to 1.1.1.

Comment: you seemed to have resolved your error, so what is your question?

Comment: faced same issue, any update ?